Scientist transfers his memory and consciousness into a robot
I recently saw a trailer where this guy I'm assuming to be a scientist has been working on a robot/cyborg. He finds out that his health is failing and that people want to use his work for a purpose he disapproves of. With his health really taking a dive he transfers his memory and consciousness into this robot. It was a pretty recent trailer so I am thinking it is either a movie that is out or coming out soon.

I hope you're not talking about Robotcop. Anyway, was it a asian trailer? An western one?

This made me think of The Schizoid Man.


This could very well be Transcendence (2014)

Dr. Will Caster is an artificial intelligence researcher who strives
  to create a machine that possesses sentience and collective
  intelligence. Extremists who oppose technological advancement target
  him, but their actions drive him toward his goal. Caster also wants to
  become part of the new technology, and his wife Evelyn and his best
  friend Max Waters, also researchers, question the wisdom of this
  drive. Caster's goal to acquire knowledge becomes one to acquire
  power, and he seems to be unstoppable. --- Synopsis from
  Wikipedia

Here are links to the trailer, the official website, plus some more clips.

It sound similar to the trailer The Prototype which has been on YouTube a couple years. IMDb lists it as still in pre-production.

The military tries to track down a humanoid drone that escapes from a government facility.

From The Verge:

A trailer involving a scientist, a humanoid robot, and technological singularity has leaked onto the internet, and it's for a movie called The Prototype. In what looks like the near future, this scientist creates a robot that the military is classifying as "the next generation of unmanned drone technology."

The trailer does show the scientist feeling unwell.

It'll be good if you can include an excerpt from the plot summary or your own commentary on how the preview matches the OP's provided criteria. (Links can die.)

Looks right Meat. Hopefully it will come out before 2018, but it is set as an indie film, so who knows.

@coleopterist There is no plot summary that I can find. I first saw the trailer a couple years ago and it didn't even have an IMDb page then. The link has been up for a long time and may never even become a feature. I suspect that the trailer is all they actually shot as a "calling card" to get funding. The trailer says it's coming out in 2013, but it's still in pre-production. Not much more I can offer than the link. Sorry.

@coleopterist Thanks for that edit. Great job. If I could give a +1 to an edit I would. Sadly, it does not elucidate on the trailer. I hope the film gets made so I can finally find out what's going on. I'm intrigued and like the style the trailer exhibits.

This sounds a lot like the premise for the Doctor Who episode The Age of Steel.
The story focuses on events in a parallel universe London, where John Lumic develops the Cyberman technology to grant himself eternal life and overcome his illness. He plans to convert the whole world's population into Cybermen and the Doctor, Rose and Mickey Smith try to stop him.

It seems highly doubtful that is what he thought was a recent movie trailer. A commercial for an old episode of Doctor Who?

You're probably right!
